# Steering behaviours accounting for the mass of the agent

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, robotics

I am using the arrive behaviour from the paper steering behaviours in webots on a simulated robot,

```
 target_offset = target - position
 distance = length (target_offset)
 ramped_speed = max_speed * (distance / slowing_distance)
 clipped_speed = minimum (ramped_speed, max_speed)
 desired_velocity = (clipped_speed / distance) * target_offset
 steering = desired_velocity - velocity
```

The problem I am experiencing is that if I give it a big slowing distance it works and robots arrives at its target with couple mm of error, however since slowing distance is so big it takes a long time to reach its destination by the time it reaches last couple of cms it is travelling so slow that it takes a couple of seconds to settle. If I give it a smaller slowing distance it begins to overshoot the target and begins acting like seek. I am gussing this is due to the formula not taking into account the mass of the robot? desired_velocity goes to 0 but never applies any breaking force.

Answer (score 0):

may be you want to have a look at the typical [PID](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDAQFjAB&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller&rct=j&q=PID&ei=C6dKTrnpAYmIsQL977C1CA&usg=AFQjCNGE0CT5nT-S7CLC-LuvB4iawq5TlQ&sig2=G_KUI30o37iwrALoktaRxQ&cad=rja) control
mass affects speed, take your previous speed into consideration.

hope it helps.